# cant read this python format ( , ) [ . . ]

Tags: python

I'm newbie and I'm reading a snippet of code like this:

```
...
proto = ('http', 'https')[bool(self.https)]
...
```

It looks like this line is letting `proto` to switch between `'http'` and `'https'`.

But what does the `( , )[ .. ]` mean? How can I make use of this style?

Comment: Note that stylistically, I would rather see `'https' if self.https else 'http'` - it's likely this is old code from before Python had a ternary operator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second element (in the brackets) is the index that will be used on the first element. So in this case, you have a single tuple:

```
('http', 'https')
```

And then a boolean that represents whether `self.https` is set. If it is true, the value will be `1`, making the call:

```
('http', 'https')[1]
```

Which will select the `https` value from the tuple. This takes advantage of the fact that `bool` is a subclass of `int`, which could potentially be considered an abuse :)

```
In [1]: t = ('http', 'https')

In [2]: t[0]
Out[2]: 'http'

In [3]: t[1]
Out[3]: 'https'

In [4]: https_setting = True

In [5]: int(https_setting)
Out[5]: 1

In [6]: t[bool(https_setting)]
Out[6]: 'https'

In [7]: True.__class__.__bases__
Out[7]: (int,)
```

For a cool usage of this technique, check out 2:14 in [this](http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2010-the-mighty-dictionary-55-3352147) video (which also happens to be a great video in its own right!). It indexes a string (`'^ '`) instead of a tuple, but the concept is the same.

Comment: so it looks like an enum.thanks for your explaination, i also test whether this work for list too for curiosity.and it works!

Comment: @user2166063 No problem, happy it helped. Since you mentioned you're just learning, you could take a look at [this](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm), which focuses on lists but covers indexing (using the `[]`'s in this case is taking the item at an index position). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It is a "switcher". This is just a short form of:

```
proto = 'https' if self.https else 'http'
```

or

```
if self.https:
    proto = 'https'
else:
    proto = 'http'
```

Also, see that you can take an item from a tuple by `True` and `False` (same as by `1` and `0`):

```
>>> print ('http', 'https')[True]
https
>>> print ('http', 'https')[False]
http
>>> print ('http', 'https')[1]
https
>>> print ('http', 'https')[0]
http
```

Comment: not much shorter and the inline if/else gives so much more readability than coercing the index...

Comment: @JoranBeasley yeah, inline style is more pythonic I think.

Comment: Indeed, not as much short as old and redundant.

Answer (score 1):

It is a dense style (and not too popular), using the fact, that boolean values can be only 0 (False) or 1 (True), which are exactly the indices of a zero-indexed two element list or tuple.

Maybe it is a bit confusing, that the index is given as a `bool`, but:

```
>>> int(bool(False))
0

>>> int(bool(True))
1
```

Also

> ... Booleans are a subtype of plain integers.

From: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex

Answer (score 0):

```
('http','https')
```

is a tuple.  As all tuples, its elements can be addressed by indices (0 and 1 in this case).

```
bool(self.https)
```

converts `self.https` into a boolean.  However, in Python boolean values are represented as the integers 0 (for false) and 1 (for true).  So,

```
('http','https')[bool(self.https)]
```

is equivalent to:

```
('http','https')[0]  #  ('http') when self.https is false, or
('http','https')[1]  #  ('https') when self.https is true
```

or

```
'https' if self.https else 'http'
```

which can be roughly understood as

```
if self.https :
    'https'
else:
    'http'
```

Form `'https' if self.https else 'http'` was introduced with Python 2.5.  Previously, several forms as the one you show were very common among Python programmers.